# Galaxy Note 3 requiring pin for lock-screen due to e-mail account

Tags: hardware

After syncing my work email with my new Samsung phone I received an on screen notice that in order to have the account synced with my phone I was required to have a password on my lock-screen.

This is very aggravating to me to constantly have to enter a pin over and over. Is there anyway to have both the email account but no required pin? I have gone to settings>Lock Screen> Screen Lock but can not seem to find what I am looking for..

Any advice would be appreciated.